# How to validate the number of characters in each word?

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-validate

This is what the input looks like:

```
<input data-delimiter=", " data-auto-focus="true" placeholder="" 
 data-autocomplete="/photos/autocomplete_tag_name" data-id-element="#tag_element" 
 type="text" value="" name="photo[tag_list]" id="photo_tag_list" 
 class="ui-autocomplete-input error" autocomplete="off" aria-describedby="photo_tag_list-error"
 aria-invalid="true">
```

using [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

As you can see it is tags separated by commas (data-delimiter). The problem is that [jquery validation plugin](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) cannot read the input for individual tags, it just looks at the total number of characters. Here is my code:

```
$('form#dropform3').validate({
  errorElement: "div",
  rules: { 
    'photo[tag_list]':          {required: false, maxlength: 20}
  },
});
```

so if the input is over 20 characters it returns an error and completely ignores the data-delimiter. The following returns an error:

```
beach, hot, picnic, watermelon, swimming, summer,
```

because it is over twenty characters.

**edit**

```
'photo[tag_list]':          {required: false, taglength: true}

jQuery.validator.addMethod("taglength", function(value, element, params) {
  var taggings = value.split(/[,]/);
  for (var  i = 0, limit = taggings.length; i < limit; i++) {
    value = taggings[i];
    if(value.length > 20) { 
      return false;
      }
      else {
        return true;
      }
  }
}, "One of your tags is greater than 20 characters.");
```

Comment: So what is the question?  How to validate the number of words instead of the number of characters?  That would have nothing to do with Autocomplete plugin.  You're going to have to write your own rule since there are no built-in rules that validate the number of words.

Comment: see edit. I want to test each tag for characters. currently i can only test the whole input for characters.

Comment: It's returning an error at 20 characters because that's all the `maxlength` rule is supposed to do... it looks at total number of characters.  If you want to allow 20 words instead, then you'll need to write a custom rule that looks at your delimiter and counts the words.

Comment: i do not want to test for 20 words, i want to check each word for 20 characters.

Comment: It does not matter... you'll need to write a custom rule.

Comment: inside of the jquery validation plug in?

Comment: yes... a custom rule for the jQuery Validate plugin.  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that jquery validation plugin cannot read the input for individual tags, it just looks at the total number of characters.

The `maxlength` method only looks at the total number of characters in the field.  It does not do anything else.

> [Quoting the docs](https://jqueryvalidation.org/maxlength-method/):  *"Makes the element require a given maximum length"*

If you want to count the characters in each word based on a delimiter, then you'll need to write a custom rule for jQuery Validate.

Use [the `addMethod()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to create your custom rule.

Example:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("taglength", function(value, element, param) {
    // your function to count characters in each word goes in here
    // use any of these arguments in your function: value, element, params
    //     value   => the present value of the field being tested
    //     element => the present field being tested
    //     param   => the parameter(s) passed in when you declare the rule.  
    // example:  // taglength: 20  // param would be 20
    // return true // if the field passes validation
    // return false // if the field fails validation and the message below will display
}, "One of your tags is greater than {0} characters."));
```

[The online examples](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/#examples:) logically compare `this.optional(element)` to the function's result using an "OR" operator.

```
return this.optional(element) || { your result (true or false) };
```

Otherwise, your custom rule will make the field mandatory all the time.  This may be ok for your situation, however, normally if you want the field mandatory you would also apply the `required` rule.

To see more custom method examples, look at the source of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/additional-methods.js).

---

**EDIT based on OP's attempt:**

within `.validate()`:

```
'photo[tag_list]': {
    taglength: 20
}
```

custom method:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("taglength", function(value, element, param) {
    var i,
        result = true,
        taggings = value.split(/[,]/);
    for (i = 0; i < taggings.length; i++) {
        if (taggings[i].length > param) { 
            result = false;
        }
    }
    return this.optional(element) || result;
}, "One of your tags is greater than {0} characters.");
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/y27v7vgc/](http://jsfiddle.net/y27v7vgc/)**

Comment: I solved this with your advice but I don't understand what you mean by taglenth: 20... I split the value and then looped through it checking if length > 20 and then return true/false.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss, `taglenth: 20` is how you would declare the rule within the `rules` object of `.validate()`.  Where `20` is the parameter that you pass into the custom method.  This way you can use the `taglength` rule on different fields using different lengths.  With your way, it's always locked into 20 characters no matter where you use it.

Comment: I thought I had it solved but the loop appears to be breaking as soon as the first tag returns true or false... so the validation stops after the first tag. it is working correctly for the first tag, just not the next tag. please see edited question.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss, you simply need to complete the loop before returning `true`.   In other words, only put the `return false` within the loop, so as soon as it hits one error, it stops as invalid.   Then at the end, OUTSIDE of the loop, have a `return true` to handle it whenever the loop completes without hitting any errors.

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss, or just see my edited answer, where I properly used the parameter and fixed the code so you don't have to worry about the method forcing the field to be `required`.